# C/C++ casting problems, unsigned char to char

Tags: c, type-conversion, printf

i have an unsigned char which i need to convert to char before printf. So the example code goes like this:

```
   unsigned char y = sample.result;  
   char x = (char)y;  
   printf("%c \n", x);
```

However, `printf` does not print `x` but if i use cout, `x` prints correctly.I have no idea why so. How to i convert a unsigned char variable to a char? Am i doing it wrong? reinterpret_casting is only for pointer and mine are not pointers. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Command prompt returns me a smiley face "☺" for the value of sample.result which corresponds to unsigned char 1. And apparently netbeans is unable to print this smiley face. I have no idea how it got translated into a smiley face. Any help?**

**EDIT 2: I just realized you can't print char x = 1; in netbeans, and printing it in command prompt yields the smiley face. Reasons? :(**

Comment: What you have compiles and works for me.  What are you expecting to get, and what are you getting?

Comment: Works for me too, with and without the cast.  Do you happen to have a value higher than 127 in `sample.result`?

Comment: If you want to use an ugly cast (ugly in a good way! :), then I believe static_cast is what you are looking for.  It probably won't solve your problem (which I believe has to do w/ Karl's comment), but is the closest cast for the job.

Comment: "☺" this is the char value displayed when i run it in command prompt. Netbeans IDE shows nothing though. Any idea guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `char x = 1` and you want a 1 to be printed out, you need to use `%d` instead of `%c` in your format specifier.  `%c` prints the [ASCII representation](http://asciitable.com/) of the number, which for 1 is an unprintable character called "start of heading."

Answer (score 0):

Try making `x` an `int` instead of `char` and see if that works. C rules required all char parameters to be converted to int, and `printf` is a C function.

Comment: "C rules required all char parameters to be converted to int" What rule?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not confident in this answer, but I just wrote a simple test program that compiles and prints the letter A without casting the unsigned char back to a char.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  unsigned char c = 'A';
  printf("%c\n",c);
  return 0;
}
```

Casting directly also worked:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  unsigned char c = 'A';
  printf("%c\n",(char)c);
  return 0;
}
```

Doing it your way ALSO worked...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  unsigned char c = 'A';
  char d = (char)c;
  printf("%c\n",d);
  return 0;
}
```

So I assume I'm doing something wrong, now.  Or maybe something else is your problem?

Comment: Well the last code wont compile, so you must have a magic compiler ;-)

Comment: Oops!  Forgot the quote before %c.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The `%c` conversion for `printf` is only for characters in the basic character set. It seems you have an extended character that you want to print, so you'd have to use the appropriate tool for that. The type for that would be `wchar_t` and the print format `%lc`. But beware this depends a lot of your execution environment, `locale` settings and stuff like that.

And BTW in many circumstances narrow types like `char` are just converted to `int` or `unsigned`, so there is no need to cast it, and in fact other than your title suggests your problem has not much to do with casting.

Answer (score 0):

Here the equation of conversion

the algorithm for `char c` to unsigned `char uc`.

```
return (c>127) ? (unsigned char)(-(256 + c)) : (unsigned char)c;
```

the algorithm for unsigned `uc` to `char c`.

```
return (uc < 0) ? (char)(256-(char)abs(uc)) : (char)uc;
```